# how to compile opencl project with kernels

Tags: compilation, kernel, opencl

I am totally a beginner on opencl, I searched around the internet and found some "helloworld" demos for opencl project. Usually in such sort of minimal project, there is a *.cl file contains some sort of opencl kernels and a *.c file contains the main function. Then the question is how do I compile this kind of project use a command line. I know I should use some sort of -lOpenCL flag on linux and -framework OpenCL on mac. But I have no idea to link the *.cl kernel to my main source file. Thank you for any comments or useful links.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In OpenCL, the `.cl` files that contain device kernel codes are usually being compiled and built at run-time. It means somewhere in your host OpenCL program, you'll have to compile and build your device program to be able to use it. This feature enables maximum portability.

Let's consider an example I collected from two books. Below is a very simple OpenCL kernel adding two numbers from two global arrays and saving them in another global array. I save this code in a file named `vector_add_kernel.cl`.

```cpp
kernel void vecadd( global int* A, global int* B, global int* C ) {
    const int idx = get_global_id(0);
    C[idx] = A[idx] + B[idx];
}
```

Below is the host code written in C++ that exploits OpenCL C++ API. I save it in a file named `ocl_vector_addition.cpp` beside where I saved my `.cl` file.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACOSX)
#include <OpenCL/cl.cpp>
#else
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#endif

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

    const int N_ELEMENTS=1024*1024;
    unsigned int platform_id=0, device_id=0;

    try{
        std::unique_ptr<int[]> A(new int[N_ELEMENTS]); // Or you can use simple dynamic arrays like: int* A = new int[N_ELEMENTS];
        std::unique_ptr<int[]> B(new int[N_ELEMENTS]);
        std::unique_ptr<int[]> C(new int[N_ELEMENTS]);

        for( int i = 0; i < N_ELEMENTS; ++i ) {
            A[i] = i;
            B[i] = i;
        }

        // Query for platforms
        std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
        cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

        // Get a list of devices on this platform
        std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
        platforms[platform_id].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU|CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, &devices); // Select the platform.

        // Create a context
        cl::Context context(devices);

        // Create a command queue
        cl::CommandQueue queue = cl::CommandQueue( context, devices[device_id] );   // Select the device.

        // Create the memory buffers
        cl::Buffer bufferA=cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, N_ELEMENTS * sizeof(int));
        cl::Buffer bufferB=cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, N_ELEMENTS * sizeof(int));
        cl::Buffer bufferC=cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, N_ELEMENTS * sizeof(int));

        // Copy the input data to the input buffers using the command queue.
        queue.enqueueWriteBuffer( bufferA, CL_FALSE, 0, N_ELEMENTS * sizeof(int), A.get() );
        queue.enqueueWriteBuffer( bufferB, CL_FALSE, 0, N_ELEMENTS * sizeof(int), B.get() );

        // Read the program source
        std::ifstream sourceFile("vector_add_kernel.cl");
        std::string sourceCode( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
        cl::Program::Sources source(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length()));

        // Make program from the source code
        cl::Program program=cl::Program(context, source);

        // Build the program for the devices
        program.build(devices);

        // Make kernel
        cl::Kernel vecadd_kernel(program, "vecadd");

        // Set the kernel arguments
        vecadd_kernel.setArg( 0, bufferA );
        vecadd_kernel.setArg( 1, bufferB );
        vecadd_kernel.setArg( 2, bufferC );

        // Execute the kernel
        cl::NDRange global( N_ELEMENTS );
        cl::NDRange local( 256 );
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel( vecadd_kernel, cl::NullRange, global, local );

        // Copy the output data back to the host
        queue.enqueueReadBuffer( bufferC, CL_TRUE, 0, N_ELEMENTS * sizeof(int), C.get() );

        // Verify the result
        bool result=true;
        for (int i=0; i<N_ELEMENTS; i ++)
            if (C[i] !=A[i]+B[i]) {
                result=false;
                break;
            }
        if (result)
            std::cout<< "Success!\n";
        else
            std::cout<< "Failed!\n";

    }
    catch(cl::Error err) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << err.what() << "(" << err.err() << ")" << std::endl;
        return( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    std::cout << "Done.\n";
    return( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

I compile this code on a machine with Ubuntu 12.04 like this:

```sh
g++ ocl_vector_addition.cpp -lOpenCL -std=c++11 -o ocl_vector_addition.o
```

It produces a `ocl_vector_addition.o`, which when I run, shows successful output. If you look at the compilation command, you see we have not passed anything about our `.cl` file. We only have used `-lOpenCL` flag to enable OpenCL library for our program. Also, don't get distracted by `-std=c++11` command. Because I used `std::unique_ptr` in the host code, I had to use this flag for a successful compile.

So where is this `.cl` file being used? If you look at the host code, you'll find four parts that I repeat in below numbered:

```cpp
// 1. Read the program source
std::ifstream sourceFile("vector_add_kernel.cl");
std::string sourceCode( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
cl::Program::Sources source(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length()));

// 2. Make program from the source code
cl::Program program=cl::Program(context, source);

// 3. Build the program for the devices
program.build(devices);

// 4. Make kernel
cl::Kernel vecadd_kernel(program, "vecadd");
```

In the 1st step, we read the content of the file that holds our device code and put it into a `std::string` named `sourceCode`. Then we make a pair of the string and its length and save it to `source` which has the type `cl::Program::Sources`. After we prepared the code, we make a `cl::program` object named `program` for the `context` and load the source code into the program object. The 3rd step is the one in which the OpenCL code gets compiled (and linked) for the `device`. Since the device code is built in the 3rd step, we can create a kernel object named `vecadd_kernel` and associate the kernel named `vecadd` inside it with our `cl::kernel` object. This was pretty much the set of steps involved in compiling a `.cl` file in a program.

The program I showed and explained about creates the device program from the kernel source code. Another option is to use binaries instead. Using binary program enhances application loading time and allows binary distribution of the program but limits portability since binaries that work fine on one device may not work on another device. Creating program using source code and binary are also called offline and online compilation respectively (more information [here](https://us.fixstars.com/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/online-offline-compilation/)). I skip it here since the answer is already too long.

Answer (score 9):

My answer comes four years late. Nevertheless, I have something to add that complements @Farzad's answer, as follows.

Confusingly, in OpenCL practice, the verb *to compile* is used to mean two different, incompatible things:

- In one usage, *to compile* means what you already think that it means. It means to build at build-time, as from *.c sources to produce *.o objects for build-time linking.
- However, in another usage—and this other usage may be unfamiliar to you—*to compile* means to interpret at run time, as from *.cl sources, producing GPU machine code.

One happens at build-time. The other happens at run-time.

It might have been less confusing had two different verbs been introduced, but that is not how the terminology has evolved. Conventionally, the verb *to compile* is used for both.

If unsure, then try this experiment: rename your *.cl file so that your other source files cannot find it, then build.

See? It builds fine, doesn't it?

This is because the *.cl file is not consulted at build time. Only later, when you try to execute the binary executable, does the program fail.

If it helps, you can think of the *.cl file as though it were a data file or a configuration file or even a script. It isn't literally a data file, a configuration file or a script, perhaps, for it does eventually get compiled to a kind of machine code, but the machine code is GPU code and it is not made from the *.cl program text until run-time. Moreover, at run-time, your C compiler as such is not involved. Rather, it is your OpenCL library that does the building.

It took me a fairly long time to straighten these concepts in my mind, mostly because—like you—I had long been familiar with the stages of the C/C++ build cycle; and, therefore, I had thought that I knew what words like *to compile* meant. Once your mind has the words and concepts straight, the various OpenCL documentation begins to make sense, and you can start work.

Comment: Adding to the thread of answers here, I have faced a similar issue naively thinking about "compilation" in normal terms, i.e how we interpret it in C/C++. The above answer by @thb makes more sense to me now. See my question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/64381665/8731673

Comment: This is not correct to say it is interpreted at runtime.  For the code to work on multiple GPU hardware, we don't know the 'compiler' that can be used.  Each GPU manufacturer has different assembler code.  So, the code is 'compile' to a GPU at runtime of the binary (CPU 'hosting' the GPU).  This is the same as 'shader' code in OpenGL.  By using intermediate representations, you can do GPU independent optimizations (front-end optimizer) and leave the back-end to happen at run time.  See: [SPIR](https://www.khronos.org/spir/).

Comment: May I suggest we try to use JIT compiling? JIT = just in time, first invented back in the Java days.

Comment: @Tomachi I know too little about just-in-time (JIT) compiling to comment intelligently, unfortunately.