# How to integrate CPP applications with OpenCL code

Tags: opencl

I'm devloping on Linux & CPP (Using Eclipse SDK).
I'm novice at OpenCL (GPU Programming)
I want to execute some of my code on the GPU (rewrite some functions with openCL and run them on the GPU).

I'm liitle bit confuse - If I will write some code (.cl files) how can I call them from my cpp application ?
I didnt saw any examples for this need.

Comment: `... I didnt saw any examples for this need.` Plenty of examples [here](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=opencl+tutorial)

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517114/how-to-compile-opencl-project-with-kernels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts of code if you want to use opencl.

A. The Kernel code.
consists of 1 to many kernel functions which perform your calculations on a device.

B. The Host code
normal c/c++ code. what happens here:

1. pick a device for the kernel to be computed on (gpu/cpu/igpu/xeon phi/...)
   in opencl you got a set of platforms which can contain several different devices. So you pick a platform AND a device.
   example: 
   platform: intel cpu+gpu opencl 1.2
   device: cpu OR IGPU
2. build your kernel

   const char * code = load_program_source("kernel.cl");
   cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&code, NULL, &err);   errWrapper("clCreateProgramWithSource", err);
3. create buffer for memory transfers to device:

   cl_mem devInput1 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, variable1* sizeof(int), NULL, &err);
4. transfer to device

   errWrapper("setKernel", clSetKernelArg(countKeyCardinality, 0, sizeof (cl_mem), &devInput1));
5. launch kernel

   errWrapper("clEnqueueNDRangeKernel", clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel_function1, 1, NULL, &tasksize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL));
6. wait for termination
   clFinish(command_queue)
7. Fetch your result from the device
   using

   clEnqueueReadBuffer
8. Proceed with your c++ code using the result created by opencl calculations.

Thats the basic idea of using opencl in your code.
Better start doing a full opencl tutorial. (just google it, you will drown in opencl tutorials)

concepts you should be familar with:
opencl host api
command queue
kernel arguments.
work group
local size
local memory
global memory
cl_mem object

Debugging opencl is possible but painfull. I would suggest doing debug with NORMAL C Code and port it to opencl if it works.

The main source for all commands is the offical API documentation, which can be found here:  [opencl 1.2 api](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/)

edit: you do not need a special IDE to code opencl.